# google Cloud Talent Solutions - indexable fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-talent-solution

I have uploaded a number of jobs to CTS and am facing the issue, that for every `job` instance information, that is listed in `job['responsilities']` is not found during searches.

Is there any way to add this field to the index?

Answer (score 0):

It seems now, that the indexable fields are actually limited and are now also documented in the official docs.
For further info on implementing google CTS, feel free to ask me.